# Java reading and writing to same file

Tags: java, no-duplicates

I'm using the following code to search specific files in my computer and write the absolute path in a text file. My problem is that every time I run this code it add duplicate lines into text file, i want to add only those lines(file path) which are not written in the text file at that time (no duplicates).. Thank you

```
public static void walkin(File dir) {
    String pattern = ".mp4";
    try {

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("D:\\nawaaaaaa.txt", true)));
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    walkin(listFile[i]);
                } else if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pattern)
                        && listFile[i].isFile()) {
                    System.out.println(listFile[i].getPath());
                    out.write(listFile[i].toString());
                    out.write("\r\n");
                    // out.close();
                } else {
                    walkin(listFile[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: one way is to delete duplicate lines in the file after you finish writing

Comment: Your code works just fine for me; how are you calling it? maybe you are calling your method multiple times (from the "caller" code) on the same dir. Using just your code again, works fine on my side

Comment: @acostache
yes i'm calling my method multiple times...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me, no idea what is the problem on your side, how you are calling it; but you can optimize your code a bit, something as follows (just very quick code, code be made nicer, but to give you an idea):

```
public class SomeTest {

    private static HashSet<String> filez = new  HashSet<String> (); 

    public static void walkin(File dir, PrintWriter out) {
        String pattern = ".mp4";
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pattern) && listFile[i].isFile()) {
                    //System.out.println(listFile[i].getPath());
                    if (filez.add(listFile[i].getPath())) {
                        out.write(listFile[i].toString());
                        out.write("\r\n");
                    }
                } else {
                    walkin(listFile[i], out);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File dir = new File("C:\\mydir");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("D:\\nawaaaaaa.txt", true)));
            walkin(dir, out);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           //
        }
    }
}
```

You can use the filez hashset to print stuff, or write your file at the end of the parsing process as well.. your choice.

Comment: I have a method walkin() and i call this method multiple times form the main method ... that's why it's generating the duplicates entries (files path) in same text file ......any solution how to prevent adding duplicate lines ?

Comment: Yes, that if (..if (filez.add(listFile[i].getPath())) {..) using the hashset will prevent duplicate entries.

Comment: i modified my code as u mentioned but same result it rewrites the same file with same file paths ever time i call this function :(

Comment: In your code, just use a hashset and check, like i do, when adding the path to the set (it's not nice, but it's a fast solution). Or use my code to test.

Comment: Tested your code :
File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
  if (listFile != null) {
   for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pattern)
      && listFile[i].isFile()) {
     if (filez.add(listFile[i].getPath())) {
      System.out.println(listFile[i].getPath());
      out.write(listFile[i].toString());
      out.write("\r\n");
     }
    } else {
     walkin(listFile[i], out);
    }
   }
  }
 }

but same problem

Comment: your code solved my problem to some extend ...it didn't duplicate lines when i call function multiple times but if i exit code and run the code again then it write duplicates again .... i think i have to read line from file compare it with current line to be written and then add line

Comment: if you exit the code and rerun, yes, it won't work (the hashset "trick" will be a lost object :-). You can maybe workaround by reading (at the beginning of your code run) the file, line by line, "setting" the hashet to contain those values and then do your logic. Just an idea, sure there are faster ways ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want duplicates in the file, you will need to keep track of the file names you have already written.  A `HashSet<String>` is going for this.  But I'm surprised the above code works at all given that you keep opening the file at the top of `walkin()` and `walkin()` itself is recursive.  You need to rethink your code a bit.  Possibly passing the `PrintWriter` into `walkin()` as a parameter.

Comment: walikin() itself is recursive as i have to search files in sub directories that's why i'm calling it again and again

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running the code multiple times ("every time I run this code it add duplicate lines into text file"), so once you finish writing to the file, you read each line and store it in a `HashSet<String>`. And use another writer to write it to the file.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename"));
for (String eachUniqueLine: `Your hash set`) {
    writer.write(eachUniqueLine);
    writer.newLine();
}
```

(It is costly as in you have to do more i/o operation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand your method into a class that perform this kind of tasks.

You have two main problem you open a writer for each directory and you call the `walkin`, for things that do not apply to your logic (and open writer again).

You should try to design a class that will be able to create an index for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    File createTempFile = File.createTempFile("mp4", ".idx");

    FileIndexer fi = new  FileIndexer(createTempFile.getAbsolutePath());

    fi.index("C:\\", "mp4");

    System.out.println(createTempFile);

}


public static class FileIndexer {

    private static final String END_OF_LINE = "\r\n";

    private final String outputPath;
    private final Set<String> index = new HashSet<String>();

    public FileIndexer(String outputPath) {
        this.outputPath = outputPath;
    }

    private boolean isValidPath(String path) {

        return outputPath != null && outputPath.trim().length() > 0; 

    }

    private boolean isValidIndexFile(File file) {

        return file.isFile() && file.canRead() && file.canWrite();

    }

    private void createIndexFile(File file) throws IOException {

        if(file.createNewFile() == false) {
            throw new IOException("Could not create index file");
        }

        this.index.clear();

    }

    private void readIndexFile(File file) throws IOException {

        isValidIndexFile(file);

        index.clear();

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
             bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            String line;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                addToIndex(line);
            }
        } finally {
            if(bufferedReader != null) {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private void addToIndex(String line) {
        index.add(line);
    }

    private PrintWriter openIndex() throws IOException {

        if(isValidPath(outputPath) == false) {
            throw new IOException(String.format("The outputPath is not valid: [%s]",outputPath));
        }

        File indexFile = new File(outputPath);

        if(indexFile.exists()) {
            readIndexFile(indexFile);
        } else {
            createIndexFile(indexFile);
        }

        return new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.outputPath, true)));

    }

    public synchronized void index(String pathToIndex, String pattern) throws IOException {

        isValidPath(pathToIndex);

        PrintWriter out = openIndex();

        try {

            File elementToIndex = new File(pathToIndex);
            index(elementToIndex,pathToIndex, out);

        } finally {
            if(out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }


    private void index(File elementToIndex, String pattern, PrintWriter out) {


        if(elementToIndex == null) {
            return;
        }


        if(elementToIndex.isDirectory()) {
            for(File file : elementToIndex.listFiles()) {
                index(file,pattern, out);
            }
        }

        if(elementToIndex.isFile() && elementToIndex.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(pattern)) {
            writeToIndex(elementToIndex, out);
        }
    }

    private void writeToIndex(File elementToIndex, PrintWriter out) {

        out.write(elementToIndex.getAbsolutePath());
        out.write(END_OF_LINE);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved (BTW i'm not sure if it is most efficient solution or not  ).......

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        File dir = new File("D:\\To Do");
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                "D:\\path.txt", true));

        walkin(dir, out);
        out.close();
        readfile();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // Replace this with a suitable directory
        // walkin(new File("D:/to Do"));
}

public static void walkin(File dir, BufferedWriter out) throws IOException {
    String pattern = ".mp4";

    // BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(
    // new FileWriter("D:\\path.txt",true));
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
            if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pattern)
                    && listFile[i].isFile()) {
                if (filez.add(listFile[i].getPath())) {
                    // System.out.println(listFile[i].getPath());
                    out.write(listFile[i].toString());
                    out.write("\r\n");
                    // System.out.println(filez);

                }
            } else {
                walkin(listFile[i], out);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void readfile() {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    String str;
    try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(
                "D:\\duplicate_free.txt"));
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\path.txt"));
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (files.contains(str)) {

            } else {
                files.add(str);
            }
        }
        for (String uniq : files) {
            out.write(uniq);
            System.out.println(uniq);
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}